# how to download image from URI on Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to download image from URI using Ruby, but it gives me this error.

my code :

```
 def image_from_json
   path = URI(@path)
   puts "path : #{path}"
   content = Net::HTTP.get(path)
   json = JSON.parse(content)
   url = URI(json["application"]["parameters"]["app_icon"])
   puts "url : #{url}"
   #image = Net::HTTP.get(url)
   Net::HTTP.start(url) do |http|
     resp = http.get("/Picto_Balmoral1.png")
     open("/Picto_Balmoral1.png" ,"wb") do |file|
       file.write(resp.body)
     end
   end
 end
```

my error :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of URI::HTTP into String (TypeError)
```

So how I can do this conversion into String ?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace for the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) instead. It's part of Rubys standard library, but you have to `require` it manually:

```
require 'open-uri'

def image_from_json
  path = URI(@path)

  puts "path : #{path}"

  content = Net::HTTP.get(path)
  json = JSON.parse(content)
  url = URI(json["application"]["parameters"]["app_icon"])

  puts "url : #{url}"

  open(url) do |remote_file|
    File.open("/Picto_Balmoral1.png", "wb") do |local_file|
      local_file.write(remote_file.read)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I try your code, but it gives me this error :
icon2.rb:28:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Picto_Balmoral1.png (Errno::EACCES)
from icon2.rb:28:in `open'

Comment: You're trying to save the file to the root path of your hard disk. It's very likely that your user does not have permission to do that. Remove the leading `/` to save to the scripts current folder, or specify a folder that you can write to.